# Rendering differences between ps_1_3 and ps_2_a

Tags: hlsl, directx9

I am trying to update a shader from `ps_1_3` inline assembly to `ps_2_a` HLSL. However the HLSL shader causes things to render differently when using `ps_2_a`. When using my HLSL conversion with `ps_1_3` it works same way as with the inline assembly.

Original assembly

```
Sampler[0] = (DiffuseMapSampler);
pixelShader = asm
{
    ps_1_3
    tex t0
#ifdef _POINTLIGHT_
    add r0.rgb, v0, v0
    +mov r0.a, v0.a
    mul_x4 r0, t0, r0
#else
    mul_x4 r0, t0, v0
#endif
#if defined(OVERGROWTH) && HASALPHA2MASK
    mul_x2 r0.a, r0.a, t0.a
#endif
};
```

Sampler and VS_OUTPUT

```
struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Pos  : POSITION0;
    float2 Tex0 : TEXCOORD0;
#if _HASSHADOW_
    float4 TexShadow    : TEXCOORD1;
#endif
    float4 Color  : COLOR0;
    float Fog   : FOG;
};

texture DiffuseMap;
sampler DiffuseMapSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = (DiffuseMap);
    MipFilter = LINEAR;
    MinFilter = LINEAR;
    MagFilter = LINEAR;
    AddressU  = WRAP;
    AddressV  = WRAP;
    MipMapLodBias = 0;
};
```

My HLSL translation

```
float4 basicPixelShaderNoShadow(VS_OUTPUT VsOut) : COLOR
{
    float4 diffuseMap = tex2D(DiffuseMapSampler, VsOut.Tex0);
    float4 outCol;
#ifdef _POINTLIGHT_
    outCol.rgb = VsOut.Color.rgb + VsOut.Color.rgb;
    outCol.a = VsOut.Color.a;
    outCol = (diffuseMap * outCol) * 4;
#else
    outCol = (diffuseMap * VsOut.Color) * 4;
#endif

#if defined(OVERGROWTH) && HASALPHA2MASK
    outCol.a = (outCol.a * diffuseMap.a) * 2;
#endif
    return outCol;
}
```

And this is the result in game
[image]
For some reason when using `ps_2_a` the colours are oversaturated.

Edit:
HLSL that fixed the issue:

```
float4 vertexColor = float4(VsOut.Color.rgb, VsOut.Color.a*2);
float4 diffuseMap = tex2D(DiffuseMapSampler, VsOut.Tex0);

float4 outCol = diffuseMap * vertexColor * 2;

#if defined(OVERGROWTH) && HASALPHA2MASK
outCol.a *= 2 * diffuseMap.a;
#endif

return outCol;
```

dont quite understand why, but it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't (yet) found definitive confirmation of this (and it's likely lost in the mists of time, in ancient documentation that no longer exists), but SM1.3 is clearly clamping intermediates to 1.0 whereas SM2 is not.

So, for example, where you have:

```
outCol.rgb = VsOut.Color.rgb + VsOut.Color.rgb;
```

And:

```
outCol = (diffuseMap * outCol) * 4;
```

If the result of any of these exceeds 1.0, SM1.3 is clearly clamping it.  To replicate the SM1.3 behaviour in SM2 you could use e.g. the [clamp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-clamp) or [max](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-max) intrinsics.

Comment: I tried using min, clamp and saturate to clamp it to a maximum of 1, but it always looked the same. The only thing I could find about clamping on the r registers is the range table on the bottom of this [article](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/columns/hardcore/dxshader3/page2.html). There it states those have minimum range of -1/+1 in 1.3 and -8/+8 in 1.4. I tested the HLSL in 1.4 and it works there, so dont think it is clamping due to range here

Comment: @Mate391 - I suggest checking the generated assembly for the SM2 version. You're definitely getting an intermediate clamped, I'm 100% positive on that, but the trick is to find *which* intermediate. It's not always obvious from the HLSL. I'd pay particular attention to the HLSL that should generate those mul_x4 lines because it's a high chance it's in there.

Comment: I played around with it some more and finally got a solution. I added that solution to the question. Still dont really understand why, but it works :D

Comment: @Mats391 Solutuons should go in Answers, not in Questions.